# Unable to 'make' anything.. Kernel-headers problem? Trying to get my RTL8723BE working

Tags: wifi, drivers, compiling, kali-linux, make

I'm a starting security/Linux student and I'm having headache-problems getting my wireless to work on Kali Linux.

Recently I've bought a new laptop, to be specific the: **Lenovo IdeaPad Z50-70-01418NL**
It comes with the wireless card: **Realtek RTL8723BE Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-E**

Lenovo only supports Windows, so I went searching for possibilities to get my wireless to work (After all, I've bought a laptop for a reason)

I Really have googled everything, and because of that I'm losing track of what is relevant and what is not, what is the right way and what isn't.

The https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723be shows the following line:
*"Code for new variety of the 8723 PCI cards - temp until code added to kernel"*

So I assume that I must compile the driver and ultimately install the driver into my system as following:

1. command 'make' to compile the driver
2. get the driver in the right place
3. Profit!

I try to 'make' the "rtl8723be" code but whatever I try it keeps giving me build errors.
Since I have been trying almost anything in the hope it will work there is a long history of errors, but mostly the errors point at the line of:

```
$(MAKE) -C $(KSRC) M=$(PWD) modules
```

Ultimately I want to get my rtl8723be driver to work.
If I use

```
ndiswrapper -i <.inf-file>'
```

It seems that ndiswrapper installs the .inf file and ndiswrapper -l is showing the driver.

But I've red that you must use

```
modprobe ndiswrapper
```

This results in:

```
FATAL: Module ndiswrapper not found
```

~~~~~~~~~~ EDIT ~~~~~~~~~~~~

So I have reinstalled the OS.
(First tried to install kernel 3.15 but still no wifi adapter)
Installed the needed kernel-headers.
And I downloaded the new "rtl8723be" from https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new

(The new version fixes the bug in trx.c = Fix version number for _ieee80211_is_robust_mgmt_frame)

When I try to use 'make' this results in the following:

```
root@Kratos:~/rtlwifi_new/rtl8723be# make
make -C /lib/modules/3.14-kali1-amd64/build M=/root/rtlwifi_new/rtl8723be modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.14-kali1-amd64'
  CC [M]  /root/rtlwifi_new/rtl8723be/dm.o
  CC [M]  /root/rtlwifi_new/rtl8723be/fw.o
  CC [M]  /root/rtlwifi_new/rtl8723be/hw.o
  CC [M]  /root/rtlwifi_new/rtl8723be/led.o
  CC [M]  /root/rtlwifi_new/rtl8723be/phy.o
  CC [M]  /root/rtlwifi_new/rtl8723be/pwrseq.o
  CC [M]  /root/rtlwifi_new/rtl8723be/pwrseqcmd.o
  CC [M]  /root/rtlwifi_new/rtl8723be/rf.o
  CC [M]  /root/rtlwifi_new/rtl8723be/sw.o
  CC [M]  /root/rtlwifi_new/rtl8723be/table.o
  CC [M]  /root/rtlwifi_new/rtl8723be/trx.o
  LD [M]  /root/rtlwifi_new/rtl8723be/rtl8723be.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
WARNING: "rtl_btc_get_ops_pointer" [/root/rtlwifi_new/rtl8723be/rtl8723be.ko] undefined!
  CC      /root/rtlwifi_new/rtl8723be/rtl8723be.mod.o
  LD [M]  /root/rtlwifi_new/rtl8723be/rtl8723be.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.14-kali1-amd64'
```

So what does this error mean? 
    WARNING: "rtl_btc_get_ops_pointer" [/root/rtlwifi_new/rtl8723be

I Have the feeling I'm almost there.

I Even tried to copy both the driver and firmware to the following folders:

/lib/modules/3.14-kali1-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8723be/rtl8723be.ko

/lib/firmware/rtlwifi/rtl8723befw.bin

Comment: This is a warning, not an error, it should be safe to ignore. Does `modprobe` work after copying the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the rtl8723be drivers, just update the kernel.

Click here and follow all steps:

https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?22638-rtl8723be-wireless-driver-installation&p=37193&viewfull=1#post37193

Comment: Nice! I've already installed 3.15 but that didn't help. After installing 3.15.1 it finally recognised the wireless card but it's still too unstable to work with. When I have time I'll try to update to kernel 3.16 and report back. For now: a big thanks!

Comment: It is now finally running stable with kernel 3.16
Thank you very much, this took a long time.
I'm still a bit frustrated why I couldn't get ndiswrapper && the compiling if the driver too work.